# Get Nunjucks templates content without render

Tags: nunjucks

I need get Nunjucks templates raw content without render it.

For example:

```
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

How can i get below result?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
```

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: For get list of scripts and styles in blocks.

Comment: If outside of the template, what for?

Comment: For custom minify and ... scripts.